# Place of "either" for different propositions

Tags: prepositions

> I want to work on either X or Y.

I have to change that sentence this way:

> I want to work either on X or in the realm of Y.

Is there any problem with it? I am doubtful about the proper placing of "either".

P.S. I know that we have to adjust place of "either" according to the verb(s).

Comment: Your sentences are okay but not in the form I am looking for: I want to say: I plan to work on this project or in the realm of power systems.

Comment: I will take either French or German. // I will speak in either French or German. // I will work in either France or Germany. = I will work either in France or in Germany. // I want to work either in France or in Germany. / I want to speak on either genetics or virology. = I want to speak either on genetics or on virology. // I want to work either on a carrier or in the dockside armoury.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily determine the right place for *either* and *both* if one will consider the point of bifurcation. In your first example the alternatives are:

```
I want to work on X
I want to work on Y
```

*I want to work on* being the longest common initial sequence, you may put *either* after it, as you did. But prepositions are so tightly "glued" to the nouns they modify that it is good style not to separate them:

> I want to work either on X or on Y.

In your second example:

```
I want to work on X
I want to work in the realm of Y
```

the common initial sequence is *I want to work*, so place *either* after it. But bear in mind that working on X and working in the realm of Y are incomparable. It is better to express the alternatives in analogous form or rewrite the sentence without *either*, for example:

> If I fail to find a job in the realm of Y, I shall seek a position where I can work on X.

Comment: +1 Nicely laid out. I wonder if we could consider *work* to be semantically different in each case of the *on/in* example, so *either* would be inserted after *to*: "... to either work on X or work in the realm of Y".